# Display chosen radio-buttons and checkboxes aside in real time before submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form in which people choose from radio-buttons and checkboxes...The thing is i need to show in the  part of the page the chosen data before they put their mail and submit!

I need to do it without refreshing so i cannot work with php for that part! How can i show the chosen data as soon as the radio-button/checkbox is clicked??

html:

```
<section id="superior">
                <form action="higuera.php" method="post" name="form" id="form">
                    <div>
                        <p><span>1.</span><i>Elegí tu abono MENSUAL:</i></p>
                        <input type='radio' name='abono' value="cinco clases" id="cinco-clases"/><label for="cinco-clases"></label>
                        <input type='radio' name='abono' value="nueve clases" id="nueve-clases"/><label for="nueve-clases"></label>
                        <input type='radio' name='abono' value="abono libre" id="abono-libre"/><label for="abono-libre"></label>
                        <input type='radio' name='abono' value="clase suelta" id="clase-suelta"/><label for="clase-suelta"></label>
                        <input type='radio' name='abono' value="clases grupales" id="clases-grupales"/><label for="clases-grupales"></label>
                        <br/>

                        <p><span>2.</span><i>Elegí los horarios de las clases según tu abono.</i></p>

                    </div>
            </section>

            <aside id="aside">
                <!-- HERE I SHOULD DISPLAY THE PREVIEW -->
            </aside>
```

this is only a portion! then the chosen data is stored in php variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to do this. Write a function in JavaScript that will display what you have selected onClick. I have written a sample code for you

```
<form>
    <input type='radio' name='abono-radio' value="cinco clases radio" id="cinco-clases-radio" onclick="displaySelectedRadio(this)" />
    <label for="cinco-clases-radio">cinco clases radio</label>
    <input type='radio' name='abono-radio' value="nueve clases radio" id="nueve-clases-radio" onclick="displaySelectedRadio(this)" />
    <label for="nueve-clases-radio">nueve clases radio</label>
    <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='abono' value="cinco clases" id="cinco-clases" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)" />
    <label for="cinco-clases">cinco clases</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='abono' value="nueve clases" id="nueve-clases" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)" />
    <label for="nueve-clases">nueve clases</label>
    <br />
</form>
<div id="displayHere">
    <div id="dispSelectedRadio"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript function

```
function displaySelectedRadio(id) {
    document.getElementById("dispSelectedRadio").innerHTML = id.value;
}

function displaySelectedCheckBox(id) {
    if (id.checked) {
        if (document.getElementById(id.value + "-disp")) {
            document.getElementById(id.value + "-disp").innerHTML = id.value;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("displayHere").innerHTML = document.getElementById("displayHere").innerHTML + '<p id="' + id.value + '-disp" >' + id.value + '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id.value + "-disp").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Live Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nzS3H/1/)

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot, is there a way to make it work for the checkboxes but not replacing de value displayed but listing the clicked checkboxes one under the other??

Comment: @MarianoUrbonas I updated the code with both radio buttons and check boxes. See the JSFiddle demo, if thats what you wanted.

Comment: It`s perfect!! Thanks a lot!! Just what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of functionality could be implemented with the use of JavaScript as it looks for DOM events. For example when the user has unfocused on the element it is stored within a variable that is then used later down the page to fill in what you need.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of how to implement this in your answer?